# Does <Query> component automatically load the cache too?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I am using the apollo client's Query component, after successfully loading data from server and on inspecting the apollo devtools console I see that the cache is empty

[image: empty cache after loading data]

in the fullstack tutorial provided in the apollo's official site I could see the cache is loaded with data, on completion of a query.

[image]

I am under the impression that cache is automatically loaded after the successful completion of a query, is that the way?

Note: the other tabs(GraphiQL, Queries and Mutations) are working fine

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code - it's hard to say how your ApolloClient is configured. It can use cache but this is optional. Read [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching)

`Apollo devtools` isn't as reliable as it should be.

For debugging puproses you can use standard `react dev tools` - inspect `<ApolloConsumer />` props for details - client ... store ... data.

**NOTE** 
Object stored in cache should have `id` and `__typename` props. Without that it won't be stored properly in the cache - and probably this is the reason why `apollo dev tools` can't display data/entries.